# PHP MySQL Selecting data from DB column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php file that inserts data to a table with this line:

```
$insert_1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_1 (`column_2`, `column_3`) VALUES ('value_2','value_3')");
```

Column_1 in table_1 is the id column which is an auto_increment column. Then, I copy the id column from table_1 to table_2 with this line:

```
$insert_2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table_2 (`id`) SELECT id FROM table_1 WHERE column_1 = ('value_1')");
```

Then, I'm trying to add the value in the id column to a session variable using this:

```
if ($insert_2) {
  $select = mysql_query("SELECT `id` from `table_1` WHERE `column_2` = 'value_2'");
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["Register"] = $select;
}
```

But when I run a var_export I'm getting a null value for $select. All these variables come from form inputs and this code has been modified to be generic. But I can't figure out why the select variable would be null. The data I'm trying to get from the database exists, but it's not being stored in the variable I want (the $select variable). I just want the id stored in a variable and to pass that to the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_query does not return the value you want. mysql_query return a mysql query result resource, to extract the data you need to use `mysql_fetch_array` (or assoc or other methods):

```
if ($insert_2) {
$select = mysql_query("SELECT `id` from `table_1` WHERE `column_2` = 'value_2'");
$myvalue = mysql_fetch_array($select);
session_start();
$_SESSION["Register"] = $myvalue[0];
}
```

Also, mysql stuff is deprecating, look at mysqli...

Comment: That seems about right. Just one more question: does that store the data as a string or as an array? I need to store the data in a variable as a string so that I can use it in MySQL statements on other pages.

Comment: $myvalue is an array containing the coloums you selected. For example if you "select * from table" then $myvalue[0] will ne column 0 value, $myvalue[1] will ne column 1 and so on. If you have multiple rows in database and you want to extract data from all of them, you have to loop the function: "while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select){$column0 = $row[0]; ...}"

Comment: See the php reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php#refsect1-function.mysql-fetch-array-examples